# Segmentation Fault error using Fasttext

Tags: linux, gcc, fasttext

I am using Fasttext on Linux 6.7, but I keep getting a Segmentation fault error.  It does not matter if I use my own data, or run the examples included with the Fasttext installation package.  In either case, I get the same error.  I am running Fasttext using gcc 3.5.2.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is pretty hard to answer as-is. Can you give a specific example of a command you try to run that fails along with the data that you used?

Comment: I fixed my issue by following the guide in https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/9129#issuecomment-406063804